# resize div depending on an image size using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, window-resize

I have an image and a colored div overlay over my image.
I get the image width and height using jquery to set the colored overlay div width and heights.
it works fine.

here is my html :

```
<div class="image_overlay">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/1xpert/1xpert1101/1xpert110100083/8712640-rainbow-cubes-3d-render-image.jpg" class="image">
</div>

<div class="image_overlay">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BrLngyC1Bto/UpO-IY1kcNI/AAAAAAAALqA/1bSQRy3G_gU/s1600/Image-b%C3%A9b%C3%A9-facebook-8.jpg" class="image">
</div>
```

my css

```
.image_overlay{
    position:relative}

.image{
    z-index:1;
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
}

.overlay{
    background-color:rgba(13, 181, 30, 0.8);
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
```

and my jquery

```
$(".image").load(function(){
    var image_h=this.height,
    image_w=this.width;
    $(".overlay").height(image_h);
    $(".overlay").width(image_w);
});
```

now I'm trying when resizing the window that the overlay get the same size of my image, using $(window).on('resize',function()... but I can't find out how to do it...

here is what I tried : http://jsfiddle.net/o4ngj624/

Can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot for your help,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".image").load(function(){
        var image_h=this.height,
        image_w=this.width;
        $(".overlay").height(image_h);
        $(".overlay").width(image_w);
    });

    $(window).trigger('resize');

});

$(window).on('resize',function() {

    var image_h=this.height,
    image_w=this.width;
    $(".overlay").height(image_h);
    $(".overlay").width(image_w);
});
```

here is Jsfiddle to see it in action :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just trigger `load` event of `image`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".image").load(function () {
        var image_h = this.height,
            image_w = this.width;
        //Use prev to find previous overlay
        $(this).prev(".overlay").height(image_h).width(image_w);
    });
});

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    $(".image").trigger('load'); //Trigger load event of image
}).trigger('resize');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/h140wcgr/)